# How do I get useState to render each time I update the state?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose, axios

I have a level up bar, where if you click the plus button it increases the bar by 10%.
I am using useEffect to grab the skills of a specific user by filtering what I get back from mongoDB(Mongoose).

I created a refreshHandler callback function that I calling to increment refresh, so that useEffect would make a request again to my back-end and I was hoping it would render the component again.

It does this once at start, then one more time and then stops rendering. (The changes are still happening in the Database, although the level only goes up one time when clicked)

> App.js

```js
function App() {
  // States
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState('');
  const [skills, setSkills] = useState([]);
  const [session, setSession] = useState({ auth: false, token: '', user_id: '', refresh: 0 });
  var { isLoggedIn, refresh } = session;

  const userAuth = (data) => {
    setSession({
      auth: true,
      token: data.token,
      user_id: data.user_id,
    });
    console.log('User logged in successfully!');
  };

  const refreshHandler = () => {
    setSession({ ...session, refresh: session.refresh + 1 });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('USE EFFECT MOUNTED!!');
    const fetchSkills = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/users/fetchSkills');
      console.log('response: ', response.data);
      setSkills(
        response.data.filter((skill) => {
          if (skill.user_id == session.user_id) {
            return skill;
          }
        })
      );
    };
    fetchSkills();
  }, [refresh]);
```

This is the skill.js component that I am using in my skillList component to show a list of skills.

> skill.js

```js
const Skill = ({ refreshHandler, text, level, skills, skill, setSkills, percent }) => {
  const levelUpHandler = async () => {
    let data = { _id: skill._id, level: skill.level, percent: skill.percent };
    if (skill.percent == 90) {
      data.percent = 0;
      data.level += 1;
    } else {
      data.percent += 10;
    }
    const response = await axios
      .put('http://localhost:3001/api/users/update-skill', data)
      .then(console.log(data))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    refreshHandler();
  };
```

I tried using an example of useRef that I found but that ended up rendering/making the axios request in a loop.

> Node.js backend - route

```js
router.put('/update-skill', function (req, res) {
  var id = req.body._id;
  var update = { level: req.body.level, percent: req.body.percent };
  console.log(update);
  Skill.findByIdAndUpdate(id, update, { new: true }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log('Success:', res);
    }
  });
});
```

MAIN GOAL:

- Each time button is clicked, update the percent/level of skill in the back-end(mongoose/ mongoDB Atlas - This is working but only one request per skill, the skill goes from 0 to 10% then each consecutive click console.logs() 10% instead of going up).
- Would like to see the progress bar increase each time button is clicked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and as if more info is needed for the problem to be clear please let me know.

Comment: Can you please provide a small reproducible example on codesandbox or a similar platform ?

Comment: Also in the useState dependency array can you try session.refresh instead of refresh ?

Comment: It's rather difficult to follow these very disjointed snippets, but based on your title it sounds like you are mutating state somewhere. It looks to me that inside `levelUpHandler` you are mutating the passed props. Seems this could be related. Without a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it's difficult to diagnose. Can you update your question to include all relevant code? If you could create a *running* code sandbox that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and live debug in that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution to my problem!
Basically when I was making a put request using axios to my backend, the request was being sent but no response was given from the backend.

Diagnosed by checking the network tab and it had a pending for the request. It seems after 5 pending request the database stalls.

So to fix it I added a return statement.

```
router.put("/update-skill", async (req, res) => {
  var id = req.body._id;
 var update = { level: req.body.level, percent: req.body.percent };
 try {
    var responseData = await Skill.findByIdAndUpdate(id, update, { new: 
true });
 } catch (err) {
   return res
     .status(500)
     .json({ error: "skill was not updated", message: err });
  }
  // This was the missing code I needed!
  return res.json({ response: "Successful", data: responseData });
});
```